# How can I change global font colors in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, themes, fonts, colors

After the 12.04 upgrade, there's a problem with the contrast between the font color and the background color. I had the same problem when I upgraded from 11.04 to 11.10, and fixed it at that time, however I don't remember what I did. Now it's back. Can somebody help?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I got the same after upgrade ...
try set a default theme ;)

Comment: I also have this problem with a lot of themes after the upgrade. Default themes work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my own question:

```
mv /home/USER/.config/dconf/user /home/USER/.config/dconf/user.old
```